# cant sent data to mysql to retrieve a list column in my api [spring data + angular + mysql]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, api

Im building an api similar to this:

[image]

SO ive a problem with the etiquetas ("tags) list, I dont know how to do it to make it retrieve the diferent values correctly in my api. Ive stablished a many to many relationship between experts and tags like this:

expert.model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;



    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="expert", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public Expert() {
    }

    public Expert(String name, String surname, String dni, String address, String mail, String phone, String created_at, String updated_at, String linkedln, String state, String rating, List<Tag> tags, String availability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.address = address;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
        this.linkedln = linkedln;
        this.state = state;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.availability = availability;
    }


my tags model:

    @Entity
    @Table(name="tags")
    public class Tag {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
    
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinTable(
                name = "experts_tags",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="expert_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
        )
        private List<Expert> expert = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public Tag() {
        } //getters and setters
```

My expertDAO is posting values in database this way:

```
@Override
    public Expert postExpert(Expert expert) {
         this.manager.persist(expert);
         return expert;
    }
```

when i try with postman i see that expert is posted succesfuly, but it retrieves all values except the tags one:

[image]

When i see my api in heroku, i see its posted ok but i dont have tags field:

> {"id":174,"name":"Paco","surname":"López","dni":"293912393D","address":"calle
> obispo 15,
> Madrid","mail":"joaquin@muñoz.com","phone":"6722292394","created_at":"15/04/2021","updated_at":"16/05/2021","linkedln":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/sara-b-54b93543/","state":"por
> validar","rating":"55","availability":"mañanas"}]

I need to make this field appear! How can i do this??? Appreciate a lot any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best expert for JSON in combinatin with Java, but the annotation `@JsonIgnore` on the field `private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>()` looks suspicious for me. A quick test from my side showed that the value of such an annotated field is not written to an json file.

Comment: thanks, now post null tags lol and appear an error WARN 4 --- [io-52473-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.model.Expert.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.model.Expert.tags, could not initialize proxy

Comment: (when i try to retrieve all experts)